# include upstart scripts when running debian:packageBin

Tags: scala, debian, sbt, deb, sbt-native-packager

i want to start my scala app as a background service on a ubuntu machine. I'm currently trying to figure out how to use the [JavaServerAppPackaging Settings](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/packager/archetypes/JavaServerApplication.scala) in my package task.

**Any suggestion, what I have to add where to include the upstart script in my deb file?**

This is my Project description incl. oneJar and debian building.

```
 lazy val root = Project(id = appName, base = file("."), settings = SbtOneJar.oneJarSettings ++ packageSettings ++ allSettings ++ Project.defaultSettings)

  lazy val allSettings = Seq(
    mainClass in SbtOneJar.oneJar := Some("Kernel"),
    resolvers += "Typesafe Releases" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases",
    resolvers += "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/",
    libraryDependencies ++= dependencies)

  lazy val packageSettings = JavaServerAppPackaging.settings ++ packagerSettings ++ Seq(
    version := appVersion,
    packageSummary := appName,
    packageDescription := appName,
    maintainer := appAuthor,
    mappings in Universal += {
      SbtOneJar.oneJar.value -> jarFsPath
    },
    linuxPackageMappings in Debian <+= (SbtOneJar.oneJar) map {
      jar: File =>
        (packageMapping(jar -> jarFsPath) withUser unixUser withGroup unixGroup withPerms "0755")
    },
    debianPackageDependencies in Debian ++= Seq("openjdk-7-jre-headless"))
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The settings should include the `packageArchetype.java_server` value eg:

```
lazy val packageSettings = packageArchetype.java_server ++ Seq(
/* ... */ 
}
```